# ¿Cómo cambio el color de fondo de una ventana en Tkinter de forma dinámica?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz

Quiero cambiar el color de fondo de una ventana en Tkinter de forma continua a varios colores, como si fuera una discoteca xd

Pero al intentarlo se pausa la ventana y sólo se cambia al último color.

Hice una lista con los colores en inglés y para configurar el fondo usé un bucle para ir recorriendo cada color y que se vaya cambiando, en teoría. Pero no me funcionó

Comment: Por favor comparte el código de lo que has hecho. Haz click en [edit] para completar tu pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example]

Answer (score 0):

#### Nota incial para el OP

En realidad, describir tu código no es la mejor opción. Esto se debe a:

- Que es mucho más dificil encontrar el error.
- Nos harías transcribir tus palabras en código. Recuerda que somos voluntarios y la gente no tiene el tiempo ni las ganas de ponerse a transcribir el código, lo que hará que tu pregunta no sea bien recibida y muchos decidan no contestarla.
- Además, quizá cuando transcribimos lo que hiciste, nosotros lo "escribimos bien" y el error no aparece en nuestra versión.

De todas maneras, logro identificar que está fallando, por ello...

te daré una respuesta aunque sea probable que me caigan negativos, ya que promuevo que las normas no se cumplan. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

#### Explicación

La ventana no se redibuja ante cada cambio estetico que hagas. Si no que, por temas de velocidad, se redibuja una vez el ciclo interno terminó. Entre las cosas que hace el ciclo interno, es llamar a las funciones que tiene que llamar y esperar a que terminen.

Eso significa que el color de fondo que establezcas, se aplicará a la ventana después de finalizada la función.

Ten en cuenta que un time.sleep "traba" a la función durante el tiempo especificado. Durante ese tiempo, también se traba el bucle interno de Tkinter, ya que queda esperando a ese sleep.

#### Solución

Un truco que se puede hacer es usar una clase que tenga la lista de colores, la posición del proximo color, la duración de cada color en pantalla y la ventana a la que le aplicaremos el fondo.

Luego, creamos un método llamado nextcolor que establece el color y suma 1 a la posición del proximo color. Y si la lista aun NO fue recorrida por completo, le decimos a Tkinter que vuelva a llamar a nextcolor luego de la duración especificada.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Disco:
    def __init__(self, window, frame_duration, colors):
        self.window = window
        self.colors = colors
        self.frame_duration = frame_duration
        self.index = 0

    def nextcolor(self):
        self.window["bg"] = self.colors[self.index]
        self.index += 1

        if(self.index < len(self.colors)):
            self.window.after(self.frame_duration, self.nextcolor)

root = tk.Tk()

disco = Disco(root, 1000, ["red", "green", "blue"])
disco.nextcolor()
```